# Setting highcharts datalabels backgroundColor with the same color of its serie

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to set the backgroundColor of datalabels with the same color of its series (UI reasons).

I've tried to use the formatter option and return a "div" with the desired styles but only the font color applies to the dataLabel.

How can I solve this problem? Follow the code I'm trying.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
                                     'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions : {
            series : {
                dataLabels : {
                    enabled : true,
                    formatter : function() {
                        return $('<div/>').css({
                            'color' : this.series.color, // works
                            'border' : '1px solid black', // don't work
                            'backgroundColor' : this.series.color // don't work
                        }).text(this.y)[0].outerHTML;
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]},
        {
            data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]}]

    });
});
```

Link to live example: http://jsfiddle.net/eVfZD/

**UPDATED:**

The solution was simple. Just set the option "useHTML" to true and set the styles to the "div" created inside the formatter function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using html tags, set `useHTML: true`, that should resolve that issue: http://jsfiddle.net/eVfZD/1/